# is there a default limit on size of npm `request.body`?

Tags: node.js, request

I am testing an internal server. When I request a page directly using `curl 'uri'` I get a lot more than when I query the same via npm using request

```
request(uri, function(err, res, body) {
    // size of body is much less than that retrieved via curl
});
```

Is there a built in threshold that I have to override manually?

Comment: Can you show an example of what site this is and what the difference in the responses are?

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out the reason for this, but after a day and a half of getting completely confounded by this (yes, weird but true, `request` was not returning the complete results that `curl` was), this started working fine. I have no idea what I was doing wrong, so I don't know what I ended up doing right. Oh well, time to move on from this one.